# unique size of the framing rectangle in zxing QR code scanner

Tags: android, zxing

I am a beginner to android. I am building an application  to work with QR code.i downloaded the source code for zxing1.5 from the link http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list. When i try to load  application with different devices i found that the framing rectangle to be in various sizes in different place,unfit to the device. please can anyone help me with this!!! Suggestion on this is appreciable. I am in real help, can anyone help me out sooner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of this area is determined in `CameraManager` and is drawn in `ViewfinderView`. It is based on the size of the display that the device reports. If it looks wrong, it is probably because the device is behaving incorrectly in this regard. You would need to debug to determine what exactly the device issue is.